# Operations and methods to be careful about in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

What operations and/or methods do I need to be careful about in Apache Spark?  I've heard you should be careful about:

1. `groupByKey`
2. `collectAsMap`

Why?

Are there other methods?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There're what you could call 'expensive'  operations in Spark: all those that require a shuffle (data reorganization) fall in this category. Checking for the presence of `ShuffleRDD` on the result of `rdd.toDebugString` give those away.

If you mean "careful" as "with the potential of causing problems", some operations in Spark will cause memory-related issues when used without care:

- `groupByKey` requires that all values falling under one key to fit in memory in one executor. This means that large datasets grouped with low-cardinality keys have the potential to crash the execution of the job. (think `allTweets.keyBy(_.date.dayOfTheWeek).groupByKey` -> bumm)

  - favor the use of `aggregateByKey` or `reduceByKey` to apply map-side reduction before collecting values for a key.
- `collect` materializes the RDD (forces computation) and sends the all the data to the driver. (think `allTweets.collect` -> bumm)

  - If you want to trigger the computation of an rdd, favor the use of `rdd.count`
  - To check the data of your rdd, use bounded operations like `rdd.first` (first element) or `rdd.take(n)` for n elements
  - If you really need to do `collect`, use `rdd.filter` or `rdd.reduce` to reduce its cardinality
- `collectAsMap` is just `collect` behind the scenes
- `cartesian`: creates the product of one RDD with another, potentially  creating a very large RDD. `oneKRdd.cartesian(onekRdd).count = 1000000`

  - consider adding keys and `join` in order to combine 2 rdds.
- others?

In general, having an idea of the volume of data flowing through the stages of a Spark job and what each operation will do with it will help you keep mentally sane.

Comment: You basically  hit  the points that immediately come to mind: shuffle, in-memory limitations, and collecting to the driver